# UK Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa - "Refused entry at border" definition

Tags: visas, uk

I am a Canadian applying for a UK Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa.

At one point during the application process, it asks if I have ever been denied entry into the UK, but I am not sure what to answer with.

A few months ago I was returning to the UK again after visiting it recently on a tourist visa. I was coming for the birthday of my friend and her son (their birthdays are close together).

Immigration was wondering why I was back again so soon and were a bit suspicious about my funds so they detained me for around 3-4 hours. They took my fingerprints and interviewed me. Afterwards they phoned my friend and after talking to her on the phone (she explained everything) they let me go through and enter the UK.

So in the end, they let me enter the UK.

So was I technically refused entry? Should I say that I was refused entry on my application? I'm afraid that it looks bad and might automatically get me denied, even though I was let through in the end.

Comment: Does the stamp you received contain the words "leave to enter"? If so, then you were not refused entry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were questioned by Immigration because of your travel history to the U.K., but you were allowed to enter. So you were not denied entry - therefore nothing to disclose on your application.

Comment: When they took my fingerprints they added me to the system. Should I elaborate on this anyways in my application in case they wonder why I'm on the system if they do research on me? I don't want to appear suspicious in any way.

Comment: @Noble If you’re in the system they will already know why. No need to mention this incident in your application, IMHO - it’s not material, nor will it automatically mean your visa will be denied.

Comment: Ok, that's good because when I was detained they were being very aggressive with me. That's where most of my worry comes from. For a while I thought they weren't going to let me go. Thanks!

Comment: @Noble Unless you’re a wanted criminal or you’re claiming asylum, there’s no risk of UK immigration not letting you go. The only question is whether they’ll let you go in the UK, or on a plane back home.