# Will This Be A Problem With My UK Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa?

Tags: visas, uk

So I'm currently working on applying for my UK Tier 5 Youth Moblility Visa. I am a 21 year old from Canada.

I am worried that a past experience in the UK will be a problem, let me explain.

A few months ago I was backpacking across Europe and spent a lot of time in the UK as I lived with some friends there. I was only there under the ordinary 6 month tourist visa. I stayed for around three months and then went back to Canada. Then around three weeks later went back to pass through Gatwick Airport to Stansted Airport to catch a flight to Norway. The woman was a bit suspicious that I was back so soon but I explained I had a flight to Oslo in two days.

Then around a month and a half later, I came back to the UK for the birthday of my friend and her son. Their birthdays are close together. Frankly, when I got there UK immigration was very suspicious because I was back for a third time and soon. Also, as I backpack and hitchhike a lot, couchsurf and do all I can to save money, I have little funds and they were suspicious about that as well.

They detained me, took my fingerprints and interviewed me under recording.

After a few hours, they phoned my friend and then decided I was ok to be let into the UK. They then let me into the UK but put a special stamp in my passport. From what I understand, the stamp signifies that I need to be asked additional questions.

I stayed for around two months as we all made plans to go to Portugal together which I didn't expect. Then we did and later I went to Ireland by myself.

During my time in the UK, my friend paid for my food and let me stay at her place. I got funds from my parents but not through my own bank account. (should I mention this on my application?)

So I was not refused entry, so I've already decided that I don't need to say that I've ever been refused entry into the UK on my application.

But they will be taking my fingerprints when I send the application to the visa center in my city. So I will probably show up on their records. I don't want them to look at me in any bad way whatsoever. I loved the UK and I very much want to live there for two years. Will this hurt my chances?

Should I mention this incident on my application so it doesn't seem like I'm trying to hide it?

I'm thinking if I don't mention it, when they're processing my application and do research they might see me show up on the system and automatically deny me because they're assuming I'm not trustworthy.

Also, will my history in the UK as a tourist and not spending money be suspicious? How can I counteract this? I will have enough money in my bank account to apply but during my time in the UK this bank account was mostly empty as I got help from my parents. I spent very very little money anyways. Around 100 pounds per month.

I could really use support on this. Thank you.

Comment: Read [my case](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87121/recently-naturalized-american-visiting-the-uk-previously-refused-should-i-appl/89879#89879). I was also fingerprinted, photographed and treated like a criminal however they subsequently let me in although my profile was [flagged](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/96671/can-a-uk-border-immigration-officer-remove-a-stop-indicator-flag) for subsequent visits until a couple months ago.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Your situation was very similar to mine, I was there for hours, photographed, fingerprints and interviewed. And your passport stamp looks just like mine. Except I'm now applying for this visa only a few months after this happened? Is there anything you recommend me do? Have you gotten a Tier 5 Youth Moblility Visa since then? Any advice at all would be appreciated. I need all the help I can get. Should I at least explain myself in my application form?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Is there any official name for the passport stamp they gave us? Hmm, maybe phoning a certain service center in the UK is an option?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Thank you very very much, it means a great deal to me.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question as what you asked yesterday? https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/123487/6188

Comment: @PeterM I'm not, that question focused on whether or not I was refused entry at the border. This one is about whether the experience should be mentioned, fingerprints, my finances when under a tourist visa, etc

Comment: How long had you planned to stay for the birthdays? Did they ask that, and what did you tell them? It sounds like they gave you a 6 mo visa anyway, but if you said, two weeks but stayed 2 months, that reflects badly on you.

Comment: Let me quote your other question for you  `Should I say that I was refused entry on my application?`  That sure sounds like a duplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this hurt my chances?

It is not a positive event so it definitely will not help your chances. It is not a deal breaker however

> Should I mention this incident on my application so it doesn't seem
>   like I'm trying to hide it?

You should not volunteer information with immigration unless it is explicitly asked. If the UK visa forms explicitly asks (been a while since I filled one out), definitely answer truthfully.

> I'm thinking if I don't mention it, when they're processing my
>   application and do research they might see me show up on the system
>   and automatically deny me because they're assuming I'm not
>   trustworthy.

That is correct. Fraud or Misrepresentation will lead to a ban, you do not want that.

> Also, will my history in the UK as a tourist and not spending money be
>   suspicious?

No. They do not know how much you spent. Plus many visitors spend little especially if they live with family.

> How can I counteract this?

**By preparing a solid application** after reading the questions here especially [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab), [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83401/after-being-refused-entry-and-removed-from-heathrow-can-i-visit-england/83403#83403), [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88875/uk-visa-refused-because-the-immigration-officer-suspects-im-trying-to-live-in-t/88878#88878) and [that](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking/39158#39158) and indeed any UK Visa question answered by [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow)

> Is there any official name for the passport stamp they gave us?

I thought so however it was explained here that it is a [normal entry stamp for non-visa nationals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89908/what-does-the-following-uk-leave-stamp-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Overall I think your chances are not bad. Although you made [frequent visits successive visits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88875/uk-visa-refused-because-the-immigration-officer-suspects-im-trying-to-live-in-t) to the UK, the visa you are currently applying for allows you to stay in the UK for an extended period of time. If you have evidence to show a compelling reason you will return to your home country afterwards, you may add it.

I think however that such nomadic behavior and lack of strong economic ties is normal and expected in people in your age group and this is recognized while adjudicating applications for this particular visa type.

Comment: Ok, this is comforting. Perhaps signed letters from my English friend explaining how she let me stay with her and one from my parents explaining how they helped me financially during my tourist stays even though I spent very little would be helpful. Make sure my application is solid and then maybe elaborate on the detainment fiasco in the "other information" section of my application so they don't think I'm trying to withhold information

Comment: ECO's have a short time within which to decide on an application. Do not deluge them with unnecessary and or verbose additional information. I would not volunteer the detainment fiasco nor the letter from your friend. A very short note from your parents about how they support you perhaps.

Comment: I agree with @Musonius Rufus. Your Immigration problem related to entering the UK visa-free. This time you are applying for a visa in advance;assuming you meet the requirements and Canada’s Youth Mobility quota hasn’t been filled https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/645584/T5__YMS__policy_guidance.pdf there’s nothing in your detainment that speaks to either the mandatory or discretionary grounds for refusal https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673999/GGFR-Section-2-v29.0EXT.PDF

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Do you think setting my intended date of travel a few months from now instead of right away or a month from now increases my chances? The incident I had was in March 2018. If I put my intended date of travel as February 2019 for example, it might look less suspicious and less like I was trying to build a foundation in the UK illegally during my past visits. I think it just looks better. What do you think? I last entered the UK in March 2018 and I left in April 2018.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus All of my history in the UK:    Oct 20th (approx) 2017 - early January 2018. Then I was in the UK a second time for 2 days in the end of January. Then I came back in March and left in the end of April.

Comment: Would be honored to have your opinion on this too @Traveller

Comment: @Noble I think that you’re worried about your entry problem affecting the decision on your YM visa application. You won’t know if it will until you apply, but if delaying will ease your worry, then delay it. If you apply now and get a refusal, you will always wonder ‘would it have been approved if I’d delayed?’. It’s your call because no-one can predict the outcome. One other thought - there is an annual quota for this type of visa, I don’t know when the clock starts or if the quota is usually filled but possibly applying early in the year may be preferable to later

Comment: The longer you wait between visits/applications, the better. That is obvious because it debunks the _the applicant must show that they do not intend to live in the UK for extended periods through **frequent and successive** visits_ problem.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Okay, I will do that then. I think putting February 15th as my intended date is good. What do you think? Also, I thought maybe in the additional information section I could add that one of the reasons I spent so much time in the UK during my tourist visas was so I could see if I wanted to apply for this visa or apply for it somewhere else. Would this be a smart thing to add or should I not bother? Good idea or bad idea? This was not something I mentioned during my detainment interview.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Also, maybe there's something else I should add. When I visited for the birthday, I told them I would be staying for two weeks. But I ended up staying for a month and a half instead because my friends and I got an idea to go vacation in Portugal for two months together. So we were preparing for that and then all left at the same time. Should I explain this as well in additional notes or not bother? Good or bad idea?

Comment: @Traveller What do you think?

Comment: `Also, I thought maybe in the additional information section I could add that one of the reasons I spent so much time in the UK during my tourist visas was so I could see if I wanted to apply for this visa or apply for it somewhere else.` No! No!! No!!! ECO's do not like uncertain people who change their mind (flip/flop) because they will think, what prevents you from changing your mind when you get there and decide to overstay.

Comment: `Should I explain this as well in additional notes or not bother? Good or bad idea?` Do not mention it. I did the same thing in 1998 (i.e stayed longer than I asked for although within the six month permitted period) and because of that the next time I went for a visa, I was denied. Do not even mention it. Listen, you are agonizing too much over this thing. Don't make it complex. Don't make it seem like you are desperate to enter the UK, that is a surefire way to get denied. You are from Canada a very developed nation. Your chances of being denied a visa are **minuscule**

Comment: @Noble I agree with Musonius Rufus, you are in danger of over-complicating this. Read the guidance https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/645584/T5__YMS__policy_guidance.pdf and keep your application factual, clear and supported by the required documents. Show how you intend to support yourself. Extending a stay in a country can have unintended consequences eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51734/cancelled-uk-visa-on-entry, there is no need to elaborate on your previous visa-free visits other than the factual eg dates.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Okay, you're right. I'm overthinking this too much. Keep it simple. And you're right, I'm from Canada. I need to calm down :) Thank you so so much for answering all of my questions. You two have been a lifesaver

Comment: @Traveller Thank you very very much for your answers. How can I show how I intend to support myself other than showing I have the minimum funds though? Or is that what you meant? I don't have a job waiting for me over there but I've listed my friend's address as where I want to stay

Comment: @Noble Well, from a practical point of view, what are your intentions for supporting yourself for up to 2 years? Are you planning on / able to stay at your friend’s address, and intending to live extremely frugally on just the minimum funds, or will you get a job or support from home? If you’ll need to work, have you researched where, what, and how much you could earn (eg https://www.gov.uk/national-minimum-wage-rates)? Point 21 of the guidance states ‘You must be able to support yourself for the entire duration of your stay without recourse to public funds (benefits provided by the state).’

Comment: @Traveller My goal is to stay at my friend's address and get a job in that town. But I don't have any job offers right now. So all I can do right now is show I have the minimum funds I think. There's a section in the visa where they ask "What is the title of the job you are coming to the UK to do?" but from what I understand it's not supposed to be there (from what I saw on another question here). As this visa does not require a work sponsor. But the question must be answered nonetheless, so I typed in "I'm not sure yet."

Comment: @Traveller Do you recommend I provide any information or documents other than my application form and minimum funds statement?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus I can only add my two most recent trips to the UK. I've been there three times. My two most recent were March-April and then 3 days in January. My first time was October-January. Should I only list my two major trips instead of my transit one, since my transit passing was so minimal? Or should I just list the two most recent, even though one was only three days. (as it asks). Sorry for the abundant questions but I do appreciate it, I really do. This will probably be my final question before I apply.